# How do I get a unicode character from an id in a variable?

Tags: java, unicode

I'm attempting to go and generate a file with every Unicode variable. I have been able to get unicode up to U+FFFF, however I need to get it up to U+231F4. I've tried searching for answers, but none of them work when the symbol id is in a variable instead of just typed.

Right now, I have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 143860; i++) {
            System.out.println((char)i);
        }
```

Instead of going up to U+231F4, it instead goes up to U+FFFF, and loops in the document it is printing to. How do I make it go to higher Unicode IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ The OP said "*I need to get it up to U+231F4*", and I answered that. But what they meant is that they wanted to print the 143,859 Code Points defined by Unicode. See the other answer. I can't delete this now that
it's been accepted. ]

Java strings aren't made of Unicode Code Points but of UTF-16 code units. You need to use surrogate pairs for Unicode Code Points above U+FFFF. For example,

```
     U+0   ⇒   0x0000            ⎫
     U+1   ⇒   0x0001            ⎪
           ⋮                      ⎬ Character in the BMP result
  U+D7FE   ⇒   0xD7FE            ⎪   in a single UTF-16 code unit.
  U+D7FF   ⇒   0xD7FF            ⎭

  U+D800   ⇒   ------            ⎫
  U+D801   ⇒   ------            ⎪
           ⋮                      ⎬ Can't be encoded using UTF-16.
  U+DFFE   ⇒   ------            ⎪   Illegal for interchange for this reason.
  U+DFFF   ⇒   ------            ⎭

  U+E000   ⇒   0xE000            ⎫
  U+E001   ⇒   0xE001            ⎪
           ⋮                      ⎬ Character in the BMP result
  U+FFFE   ⇒   0xFFFE            ⎪   in a single UTF-16 code unit.
  U+FFFF   ⇒   0xFFFF            ⎭

 U+10000   ⇒   0xD800, 0xDC00    ⎫
 U+10001   ⇒   0xD800, 0xDC01    ⎪
           ⋮                      ⎬ Those outside result in two.
 U+231F2   ⇒   0xD84C, 0xDDF2    ⎪
 U+231F3   ⇒   0xD84C, 0xDDF3    ⎭

 U+231F4   ⇒   0xD84C, 0xDDF4    ⎫
 U+231F5   ⇒   0xD84C, 0xDDF5    ⎪
           ⋮                      ⎬ We don't care about these.
U+10FFFE   ⇒   0xDBFF, 0xDFFE    ⎪
U+10FFFF   ⇒   0xDBFF, 0xDFFF    ⎭
```

For the details on surrogate pairs, you can consult the Wikipedia page for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

##### Solution 1: `printf %c`

These details don't matter because we can use `printf %c` encode a Unicode Code Point into UTF-16 code units.  (Kudos to @VGR.)

```java
for (int cp=0; cp<0x231F4; ++cp) {
   if (cp < 0xD800 || cp >= 0xE000) {
      System.out.printf("%c%n", cp);
   }
}
```

Optimized:

```java
for (int cp=0; cp<0xD800; ++cp) {
   System.out.println((char)cp);
}

for (int cp=0xE000; cp<0x10000; ++cp) {
   System.out.println((char)cp);
}

for (int cp=0x10000; cp<0x231F4; ++cp) {
   System.out.printf("%c%n", cp);
}
```

##### Solution 2: `Character.toChars`

Alternatively, we can use `Character.toChars(codePoint)` to produce a `char[]` containing the UTF-16 code units of a Unicode Code Point.

```java
for (int cp=0; cp<0x231F4; ++cp) {
   if (cp < 0xD800 || cp >= 0xE000) {
      System.out.println(Character.toChars(cp));
   }
}
```

Optimized:

```java
for (int cp=0; cp<0xD800; ++cp) {
   System.out.println((char)cp);
}

for (int cp=0xE000; cp<0x10000; ++cp) {
   System.out.println((char)cp);
}

for (int cp=0x10000; cp<0x231F4; ++cp) {
   System.out.println(Character.toChars(cp));
}
```

I believe the above still creates a lot of arrays. Implementing the conversion yourself avoids that and should thus be even faster.

```java
// Up to but excluding U+231F4 ⇒ 0xD84C, 0xDDF4

for (int cp=0; cp<0xD800; ++cp) {
   System.out.println((char)cp);
}

for (int cp=0xE000; cp<0x10000; ++cp) {
   System.out.println((char)cp);
}

char pair[2];
for (int hisurro=0xD800; hisurro<0xD84C; ++hisurro) 
   pair[0] = (char)hisurro;
   for (int losurro=0xDC00; losurro<0xE000; ++losurro) 
      pair[1] = (char)losurro;
      System.out.println(pair);
   }
}

pair[0] = 0xD84C;
for (int losurro=0xDC00; losurro<0xDDF4; ++losurro) 
   pair[1] = (char)losurro;
   System.out.println(pair);
}
```

---

Note that result is not going to be entirely readable in your terminal. The output includes non-printable characters (e.g. control characters), marks (which combine with other characters), unassigned Code Points, private use Code Points, etc.

Comment: Another alternative:  `for (int i = 0; i < 143860; i++) System.out.printf("%c%n", i);`

Comment: @VGR, Thanks, my knowledge of Java s limited. Added to answer.

Comment: Instead of wrestling with the obsolete `char` type and wrangling surrogate pairs, just use [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers. Java has full support of code points, though not obvious in the awkward and aging API. See code in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68583226/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque uh, Did you read my answer? Both of the solutions I posted use code points and not chars. Merely the optimized versions of those solutions use chars, because using code points would not provide any optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Here is a one-liner. (For fun, not what I would recommend.)

```java
IntStream
        .rangeClosed( 0 , Character.MAX_CODE_POINT )
        .filter(
                codePoint ->
                        !
                                List
                                        .of( Character.CONTROL , Character.FORMAT , Character.SURROGATE , Character.PRIVATE_USE , Character.UNASSIGNED )
                                        .contains( ( byte ) Character.getType( codePoint ) )
        )
        .forEach(
           codePoint -> System.out.println( codePoint + " code point is named: " + Character.getName( codePoint ) + " = " + Character.toString( codePoint ) )
        )
;
```

When run.

```
32 code point is named: SPACE =  
33 code point is named: EXCLAMATION MARK = !
34 code point is named: QUOTATION MARK = "
…
917997 code point is named: VARIATION SELECTOR-254 = 
917998 code point is named: VARIATION SELECTOR-255 = 
917999 code point is named: VARIATION SELECTOR-256 =
```

## Avoid `char`

The **`char` type in Java is obsolete**. That data type is unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode and supported by Java.

Java now offers full support of code points. Unfortunately, that support is not obvious, having been years later bolted on to aging APIs in `Character`, `String` , and `StringBuilder` classes. You have to look past the outmoded methods involving `char`.

## Use code points

Get in the habit of using Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers, without any `char`. A code point is a number assigned to each and every one of the 143,859 characters defined by [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Those code point numbers are assigned from a range 0 to 10FFFF hex, 0 to 1,114,111 decimal. Obviously most of that million-wide range is empty, either currently unassigned or set-aside as a reserve for private usage.

You said:

> however I need to get it up to U+231F4.

No, you need to go to U+10FFFF (1,114,111 decimal).

By the way, Unicode is always growing. So, do not get attached to a character count such as 143,860. We can never have too many emojis! And some serious characters are still being added too.

So your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 143_860; i++) {  // NO! Wrong limit.
```

… needs to change its limit from 143_860 to 1_114_111 decimal (10FFFF hexadecimal).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1_114_111; i++) { // YES! Correct limit.
```

Or, for this limit, use the constant [`Character.MAX_CODE_POINT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_CODE_POINT).

```
for (int i = 0; i < Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; i++) {  // Use named constant rather than "magic" mystery number.
```

One more thing… the `MAX_CODE_POINT` is *inclusive*, so we should be testing for "is less than OR equal to" rather than "less than". Change `<` to `<=`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; i++) {  // Use named constant rather than "magic" mystery number.
```

The [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) class can tell us if a [code point is valid](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint(int)) or not. All code points from 0 to the maximum 1,114,111 are valid numbers. Negative numbers and numbers over the maximum are invalid.

And that same class can tell us what kind of character is represented by a code point. The Unicode Standard defines 30 kinds, formally known as “General Category”. These categories are defined on the `Character` class as named constants, unfortunately mixed with other different constants.

We would like to skip over certain of those categories, specifically five:

- `Character.CONTROL`
- `Character.FORMAT`
- `Character.SURROGATE`
- `Character.PRIVATE_USE`
- `Character.UNASSIGNED`

To determine the category of a code point, call [`Character.getType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)). Unfortunately, that method returns a mere `int` rather than a dedicated enum object.

As listed above, the `Character` class defines various `byte` constants for the general categories, but has no way to easily convert the number returned by `getType` into a category name. See the related Question, [*How to get the category name of the character type in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24248369/642706). [There is a feature-request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217630) on the books, but not yet implemented. So we must roll-our-own.

Here we use a list of `Byte` objects named `unicodeGeneralCategoryCodesToAvoid`, one element for each of the five constants of interest.

To move from a code point `int` number to an actual character, call [`Character.toString( codePoint )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) to produce a `String` containing a single character.

To get the official name for a character as defined by the Unicode Standard, call [`Character.getName( codePoint )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getName(int)).

```java
List < Byte > unicodeGeneralCategoryCodesToAvoid = List.of( Character.CONTROL , Character.FORMAT , Character.SURROGATE , Character.PRIVATE_USE , Character.UNASSIGNED );
for ( int codePoint = 0 ; codePoint <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT ; codePoint++ ) {
    if ( Character.isValidCodePoint( codePoint ) )    // If code point is valid.
    {
        if ( unicodeGeneralCategoryCodesToAvoid.contains( ( byte ) Character.getType( codePoint ) ) ) // If control character or if unassigned code point, skip it.
        {
            // No code needed. Skip over this code point as it does not represent a printable character.
        } else {
            System.out.println( codePoint + " code point is named: " + Character.getName( codePoint ) + " = " + Character.toString( codePoint ) );
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println( "ERROR - Invalid code point number: " + codePoint );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
INFO - Demo starting. 
32 code point is named: SPACE =  
33 code point is named: EXCLAMATION MARK = !
34 code point is named: QUOTATION MARK = "
35 code point is named: NUMBER SIGN = #
36 code point is named: DOLLAR SIGN = $
37 code point is named: PERCENT SIGN = %
…
123 code point is named: LEFT CURLY BRACKET = {
124 code point is named: VERTICAL LINE = |
125 code point is named: RIGHT CURLY BRACKET = }
126 code point is named: TILDE = ~
160 code point is named: NO-BREAK SPACE =  
161 code point is named: INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK = ¡
162 code point is named: CENT SIGN = ¢
…
917997 code point is named: VARIATION SELECTOR-254 = 
917998 code point is named: VARIATION SELECTOR-255 = 
917999 code point is named: VARIATION SELECTOR-256 = 
INFO - Demo ending.
```

---

For more of my code for dealing with Unicode General Category, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68597823/642706) to the Question, [*How to get the category name of the character type in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24248369/642706).

Comment: @ikegami The OP may have *intended* to work with code points. But given the limit of `143860`, they obviously have conflated the *count* of assigned code points with the *range* of possible code points (1,114,111).

Comment: Because it didn't do what the OP asked. But it does do what the OP meant. Which I mentioned earlier. Anyway, comments removed to avoid confusion. Also gave +1 a while back