# How to convert Unicode to char

Tags: java

I would like to get the Unicode character corresponding to the input int. You can assume that input `int` can be represented as `char` in Java.

Comment: Similar: [*How do I get a unicode character from an id in a variable?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68581899/642706)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A couple tips as a new user here: (a) Be respectful to your future readers: Use proper uppercase and such. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, and less like a casual chat room. (b) Eliminate chit-chat such as "Thanks in advance", as that is seen merely as a distraction here. Focus on the technical issue. I made edits to your Question to address both points.

Comment: Should point out that in real world applications, it is INCORRECT to assume that a Unicode code point may be represented as a single `char` or a `Character`.  Or that every integer in the range `0` ... `65535` represents a Unicode code point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Character.toString( 65 )
```

> A

## `Character.toString( codePoint )`

You said:

> I would like to get the unicode character corresponding to the input int

```
String character = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

See these examples [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/MtNE3m):

```
System.out.println( Character.toString( 65 ) ) ;               // "A"
```

> A

```
String faceWithMedicalMask = Character.toString( 128_567 ) ;  // "" = FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK.
System.out.println( FaceWithMedicalMask ) ;
```

> 

Not all code points are assigned to encoded characters. Check that your input integer [is indeed a valid code point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint(int)).

```
int codePoint = 128_567 ;
String faceWithMedicalMask = null ;
if( Character.isValidCodePoint( codePoint ) ) {
    faceWithMedicalMask = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
} else {
    … deal with invalid code point
}
```

## Avoid `char` & `Character` types

You said:

> You can assume that input int can be represented as char in java.

No, you cannot assume that.

Most of the over 140,000 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and supported by Java, **cannot be represented by the `char`** type. As a 16-bit value, a `char` is physically incapable.

The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, supplanted by [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) support added in Java 5+.

## Casting `int` to `char`

If you insist on using `char`, against my recommendation, then know that you can cast an `int` number into a `char` value.

```
char c = (char) 66 ; 
System.out.println( c ) ;
```

> B

**BEWARE:** This only works for code points in the range of 0 to 65,535. Most Unicode characters have code points beyond that range, going up to 1,114,111.

That 0 to 65,535 range is known in Unicode as the [*Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). Java provides a method to test for this range, [`Character.isBmpCodePoint(int codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isBmpCodePoint(int)). You can check before your cast:

```
if( Character.isBmpCodePoint( codePoint ) ) {
    char c = (char) 66 ; 
} else {
    … deal with input out of range
}
```

Not all code points are assigned to encoded characters. Check that your input integer [is indeed a valid code point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint(int)).

```
if( Character.isBmpCodePoint( codePoint ) ) {
    if( Character.isValidCodePoint( codePoint ) ) {
        char c = (char) 66 ; 
    } else {
        … deal with invalid code point
    }
} else {
    … deal with input out of range
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that not all `int` values in the range `0` to `65535` are *valid* code points.  For example, the surrogates.

Comment: @StephenC So noted in my edits. Thank you.